root user can't read `gio mount`ed smb share
As a non-root user I can run
$ gio mount smb://raspberrypi.local/shared

and the drive mounts fine.  However, the root user doesn't have read permissions for it somehow.
$ stat /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=raspberrypi.local,share=shared

  File: /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=raspberrypi.local,share=shared
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 48h/72d Inode: 16          Links: 1
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/     max)   Gid: ( 1000/     max)
Access: 2024-07-19 19:55:20.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2024-07-19 19:55:20.000000000 -0700
Change: 2024-07-19 19:55:20.000000000 -0700
 Birth: -

$ sudo stat /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=raspberrypi.local,share=shared
stat: cannot statx '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=raspberrypi.local,share=shared': Permission denied

This is surprising because I thought everything a normal user could do, the root user could do too.
How can I make my smb share visible to both my user and root?
version:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ gio --version
2.72.4


Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.

Long ago, it was recognized that allowing the remote root user privileged NFS access was a Security Vulnerability. Just because one has root locally should not grant root access to the remote (NFS) filesystem.  NFS remaps root's UID to the nobody unprivileged user.


How can I make my smb share visible to both my user and root?

By not using a gio mount. That creates a virtual filesystem that is accessible only to the user that invokes it.
I recommend a cifs mount instead.
Make sure the cifs "helper" program is installed:
sudo apt install cifs-utils

Create a mount point ... say /media/PiShared:
sudo mkdir /media/PiShared

Then mount the share to that mountpoint:
sudo mount -t cifs //raspberrypi.local/shared /media/PiShared -o guest,uid=1000

Note:"guest" assumes the share on the Pi does not require credentials to access. If it needs a username pass it with the username parameter - replacing XXX below with a real user name.:
sudo mount -t cifs //raspberrypi.local/shared /media/PiShared -o username=XXX,uid=1000

CIFS also creates a virtual fileysstem but in this case it will mount the share with owner set to the user identified by uid=1000 with read access to everyone else.
